# Css code in javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

I have this javascript method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function MyFunction(sender, eventArgs) {
       if (someCondition) {
           //css
       }
    }
</script>
```

The css code I want to be executed is:

```
<style type="text/css">
          .classInsideTheClassWhichEntersTheIf
          {
          background: url(Images/myImage.png) !important;
          }
</style>
```

but only for those cells that enter the if condition above. If I write it outside it works but for every cell. Is something like this possible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "only for cells that enter the condition"? Is your JavaScript defined inline? Where is your style definition? I do hope not inside the document body?

Comment: Please provide more details on your code. There are no cells in your code, we dont know what is sender, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

**Option 1.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function MyFunction(sender, eventArgs) {
       if (someCondition) {
          someelement.style.cssText = "background: url(Images/myImage.png) !important;"
       }
    }
</script>
```

**Option 2.**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function MyFunction(sender, eventArgs) {
           if (someCondition) {
              someelement.className = "someclass"
           }
        }
    </script>
```

where,

```
<style>
.someclass{
background: url(Images/myImage.png) !important;
}
</style>
```

**Option 3**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           function MyFunction(sender, eventArgs) {
               if (someCondition) {
                  someelement.setAttribute('style', 'background: url(Images/myImage.png) !important;');
               }
            }
        </script>
```

Here is a pseudo code,

```
if(condition)
  someelement.style.cssText = "background: url(Images/myImage.png) !important;";
```

Comment: Yeah, call the MyFunction for each of your filtered in element in the for loop. Ill update hang on.

Comment: It gets called for each element, it's an event, I can't call it for specific elements.

Comment: Ok, whenever your condition is satisfied, then make the css changes on those elements using cssText property by appending the new change or by using a class that has all the properties of the old element along with the new css property which you want to add.

Comment: I've updated it, You need to keep track of your elements. Check for the position based on the for loop iterator count and set that element with the change you want. I cant tell you much from whatever you have provided. You need to show us even the markup.

Answer (score 5):

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function MyFunction(sender, eventArgs) { 
       if (someCondition) { 
          someelement.style.backgroundImage = "url(Images/myImage.png)"; 
       } 
    } 
</script>
```

`!important` is unnecessary here, because inline styles override non-inline styles.

Comment: +1 for simplicity (even though you missed the opportunity to say "!important is unimportant here").

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the style property of elements that you need. But more flexible method is to define a css-class with that css-code, and just add this class to filtered elements.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine that you have a cell with `id="myCell"` and your condition is true for what you want.
Now you can do it using something like this:

```
$(document).ready(functio() {
   function SET(id) {
      $('#'+id).css('background-image','yourNewImage.png');
   }
   if (condition == true) {
      SET('myCell');
   }
});
```

Using `.css`, you can assign any value to each CSS property for each element. Here I changed the background-image.