# How can I give an HTML 5 banner a transition animation on iOS?

Tags: ios, html, css, css-transitions, html5-animation

I'm implementing an app demo that after a prompt (where it calls back to the server) displays an HTML5 banner at the top of the screen. However, I can't figure out how I can animate the HTML5 banner to transition vertically onto the screen from the top.

The type of transition animation I'm talking about is here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCkg3llsxZI&t=0m8s - although the animation I need is a simple vertical transition without the 3D effect that native iOS push notifications have.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSS3 transforms/transitions. This is a lot faster and better than using javascript or a JS library such as jQuery.
[see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions)

If you want more detailed animations, use CSS3 animations.
[see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations)

And most importantly, to ensure full cross-plat support of CSS3, install Modernizr and run some shims.
[see here](http://www.netmagazine.com/features/making-html5-and-css3-work-polyfills-and-shims)

EDIT: If you want to trigger the above CSS3 with iOS touch [gestures functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898627/what-is-the-difference-between-pan-and-swipe-in-ios), then define those styles [inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561492/css-code-in-javascript-function) of the functions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help, really appreciate it! I followed the links you provided and CSS3 certainly seems like the best way to implement the animation, however I can't seem to find any examples relating to vertical transitions (they all seem to be horizontal!) - are there any other resources out there you are aware of? A brief google for a vertical drop down transition revealed nothing...

Comment: Think I've found the transition I'm looking for - should this work in iOS? http://jsfiddle.net/R8zca/4/

Comment: Look for videos/articles by Michael Palermo, he is a famous CSS3 guru with lots of tutorials/demos on the web discussing new CSS3 syntax and effects. The new iOS is certainty HTML5/CSS3 friendly. You may have to include vendor specific prefixes (-iOS) at the beginning of each style definition for older iOS versions.